# no data in jtl file and how to display jmx result in GUI using java code

Tags: java, user-interface, jmeter

I have two combining two questions. both r related to each other. I am trying run jmx script using java. I used following code to store result in jtl file
SaveService.loadProperties();

```
FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("/Users/vihang_shah01/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/extras/firstTry.jmx");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HashTree hash=SaveService.loadTree(file);
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");//$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.println("length:"+summariserName.length());
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        String logFile = "/Users/vihang_shah01/Desktop/file.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        hash.add(hash.getArray()[0], logger);
        file.close();


        jmeter.configure(hash);
        jmeter.run();
```

in my output jtl file is created. but is empty where in my console o/p is showing like this way

```
summary =      0 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

my jmx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="first try" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1455186838000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1455186838000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="speciality" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/speciality</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">names</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(dentist|cardio)</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NONE</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Sample.scope">all</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
          </DebugPostProcessor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">names</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">name</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
        </ForeachController>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="${name}" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/names?speciality=${name}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
              <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
            </DebugPostProcessor>
            <hashTree/>
            <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">times</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(deepak|kk|kumar|bs)</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NONE</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
            </RegexExtractor>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">times</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">time</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
          </ForeachController>
          <hashTree>
            <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="${time}" enabled="true">
              <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
              </elementProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/appointments?things=${time}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            </HTTPSamplerProxy>
            <hashTree>
              <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
              </DebugPostProcessor>
              <hashTree/>
            </hashTree>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="filename">specialist</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
        </CSVDataSet>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

and also I want to result of this jmx file as a graph or bar any kind of GUI mode using java code. Is there any way for this??thanks in advance

Comment: I checked logs it's showing "/Users/vihang_shah01/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE/JmeterJson/specialist" not found. where this path has been set? in jmx file?

Comment: i checked in net. But I dint find any way to generate graph using eclipse. plz provide any reference or anything for this.